# 'No suitable driver found' error  for using a database in a Web Service on Glassfish server

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, netbeans, jdbc

I have a Java Web Application and using an operation of it from a consumer Java App i want to handle a MySQL database. When i am trying to get a connection to the database i get a:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql
```

I have put the JDBC connector jar to the classpath of both my Web App and the Java App that tries to consume the Web Service. I am using NetBeans IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the connector in the `glassfish/lib` folder and restart the server.