# Cannot connect to a mysql database with JSP, Glassfish

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, glassfish

I have previous JSP experience but with using Tomcat and Resin and I would like to connect to a mySQL database using Glassfish and hoped that more or less copy and pasting the code would work.

The code is:

```
try {
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
    } catch (Exception E) {
        System.out.println("First: " + E);
    }

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/DBName", "Username", "Password");
```

The errors I get when I look into my server logs are

> [#|2012-03-09T13:50:21.900+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=67;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|First:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver|#]
>
> [#|2012-03-09T13:50:22.009+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=67;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|java.sql.SQLException:
>   No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.xx.xx.xx/SmarterStudents|#]

I have put the mysql-connector-java-5.0.7-bin.jar into the domain/lib folder and threw it into the WEB-INF/lib folder just to be safe and it still wouldn't work for me.

I'm at my wit's end now, I just don't know what to do. D:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8873211/870122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the old and deprecated driver class name for the very first releases of the MySQL JDBC driver `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` when it was still a hobby project, while you're using one of the more recent releases of the MySQL JDBC driver which has the driver class name `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Fix the classname accordingly.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Make sure that you're reading the [official MySQL JDBC driver documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) instead of some random and heavily outdated resource/book/tutorial.

As to the placement of the JAR file, when you're managing the connections *yourself* in your web application, the JAR can be placed in both server's own `/lib` or webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. But when you're letting the server manage the connections (which will usually use a shared connection pool which is *way* much faster), then the JAR must be placed in server's own `/lib` folder. The one in the deployed webapp(s) will be ignored anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Try working with [JdbcOdbcDriver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html) , but generally they say it should be used as a last resort.

```
try
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:db","root","root");
}catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This should work for MySQL database, you need to install the connector for this as well, and the username and password generally for MySQL is root and root, respectively.

Comment: -1: Don't use the ODBC bridge when you have the option of using a JDBC implementation of the vendor